# Two way lookup hash or other data strcuture

Tags: algorithm, hash, dns, trie

I am implementing DNS cache. I am planning to use hash or Trie data structure for it.
Is there any way where I can do Forward and reverse lookup from the same Data ?
I dont want to maintain 2 records, one for forward and second for reverse lookup.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what if two different keys have same value? what do you plan to return in reverse lookup?

Comment: In that case I am planning to create a link-list. And keep both the entries as valid entry.